# Android - save data to my own data server

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, openid

I'm programming an Android app, where I have to store pictures to some online data storage plus I want to use OpenID for authentication, so I don't have to keep users and their passwords on my side of the server.

I've looked at [LeanEngine](http://www.lean-engine.com/), which does just that, but it's a shame that you can only store your data to the Google Storage (and it's running on Google App Engine). I want to store data on my own server.

My questions are:

1. What software should I use on the server side of my linux to enable such a functionality?
2. Is OpenID really such an advantage that I should use it. I mean, because there is a lack of support for that (for my own server to use), it can only be a burden and not exactly an advantage?

Basically I need to know what would you suggest for syncing pictures with an online data storage service, which needs to run on **my own** server.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most notable solution is [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) in Android, which I didn't even know existed. Together with **REST** they are pretty great at achieving anything I want.

Answer (score 2):

First, the title is misleading - if you need to save data to your own server, then this is not "the cloud".

1. LeanEngine uses [AppEngine Datastore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/overview.html), not [Google Storage](https://developers.google.com/storage/).
2. LeanEngine is just a small library that runs on your AppEngine instance. So this is your own instance and your own data.
3. If you still want to run your own server, than the obvious solution would be to implement OpenID on your own server. There are a few solutions for Java, the most well-supported is probably [Spring Social](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social). It supports multiple authentication schemes: OpenID, Facebook, Twitter, etc..

There is also an [Android client](http://www.springsource.org/spring-android) which supports authntication and easy use of REST services.